# Ionic2: Unsubscribe Event to Avoid Duplicate Entries?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ibeacon

I've followed [this tutorial](https://ionicallyspeaking.com/2017/01/16/creating-a-beacon-application-with-ionic-2/) which outlines adding monitoring beacons in an Ionic 2 application. I have it working great: when the view loads, it initializes and begins listening for beacons:

**home.ts**

```
    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.beaconProvider.initialise().then((isInitialised) => {
                if (isInitialised) {
                    this.listenToBeaconEvents();
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

This calls the `listenToBeaconEvents` function which populates a list in the view with all of the beacons:

**home.ts**

```
    listenToBeaconEvents() {
        this.events.subscribe(‘didRangeBeaconsInRegion’, (data) => {

            // update the UI with the beacon list
            this.zone.run(() => {

                this.beacons = [];

                let beaconList = data.beacons;
                beaconList.forEach((beacon) => {
                    let beaconObject = new BeaconModel(beacon);
                    this.beacons.push(beaconObject);
                });

            });

        });
    }
```

I'm able to stop ranging using `this.beaconProvider.stopRanging()` that calls a function from the below function:

**beacon-provider.ts**

```
    stopRanging() {
        if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
            // stop ranging
            this.ibeacon.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(this.region)
                .then(
                () => {
                    console.log('Stopped Ranging');
                },
                error => {
                    console.error('Failed to stop monitoring: ', error);
                }
                );
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm having is this - in the original tutorial the beacon list is shown at the root, there's no other navigation. I've moved it to a different view, and if the user exits and re-enters the view, it re-initializes and loads everything, resulting in duplicate list entries.

I've tried creating a function within beacon-provider.ts to call before the view exits, but I can't figure out how to keep the subscriptions/events from duplicating.

I've tried `this.delegate.didRangeBeaconsInRegion().unsubscribe()`, and some other variations but they all result in runtime errors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your case you are using Ionic's [Events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) API which has its own [`unsubscribe(topic, handler)`](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/v3/src/util/events.ts#L61) function.

In your component, whenever you need to unsubscribe, you should call this with the same topic:

```
this.events.unsubscribe(‘didRangeBeaconsInRegion’);
```

This will remove *all handlers* you may have registered for the `didRangeBeaconsInRegion`.

If you want to unsubscribe one specific function, you will have to have registered a named handler which you can send with unsubscribe.

```
this.events.unsubscribe(‘didRangeBeaconsInRegion’,this.mySubscribedHandler);
```

And your **home.ts** would look like:

```
 mySubscribedHandler:any = (data) => {

            // update the UI with the beacon list
            this.zone.run(() => {

                this.beacons = [];

                let beaconList = data.beacons;
                beaconList.forEach((beacon) => {
                    let beaconObject = new BeaconModel(beacon);
                    this.beacons.push(beaconObject);
                });

            });

        }

    listenToBeaconEvents() {
        this.events.subscribe(‘didRangeBeaconsInRegion’,this.mySubscribedHandler);
    }
```

Comment: Could you specify where I declare the subscription class property? I've tried in both `listenToBeaconEvents()`, within the `export class TakeTour` under the constructor, and in beacon-provider.ts but I get errors on all three. Thank you!

Comment: you need to declare it as a class variable in the class where you are subscribing.. remember to also `import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';`

Comment: Okay most of the errors are gone, now I just have one left: "Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Subscription', and then `this.beaconEventSubscription` is highlighted as the error line.

I have `Subscription` imported at the top, `public beaconEventSubscription: Subscription` in the constructor.

Comment: It shouldn't be in the constructor  parameter..it is just a class variable.. Declare it within the class outside the constructor

Comment: Hi @suraj, thanks for continuing to assist, I'm still getting a "Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Subscription'. I've updated the question above to show the full code in case I'm missing something

Comment: @Lauren Since you are using Ionic's event api, it would be different from observable-subscription..I  updated the answer..This should solve it

Comment: thank you ,I have found what I'm looking for .Can I ask how to pass multiple parameters to that mySubscribedHandler ?  this.events.subscribe(‘didRangeBeaconsInRegion’,this.mySubscribedHandler);