# Ionic event fires too many times. Incremented by one each time it's triggered?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, socket.io, ionic2, ionic3

*TL;DR: Subscription event fires too many times.*

I have a event set up, that gets fired, when real time data comes in through a socket.

Through console logs I figured out, that the real time data correctly only comes in once. The event that gets fired, when the real time data comes in, also only gets fired once:

```
console.log("Event publish got fired!");
this.events.publish(EVENTSLUG_STAMP_UPDATE);
```

I only see this console log once each time the data comes in.

Here comes the weird part: the subscription events triggers multiple times! For each time real time data comes in, it triggers once more.

```
this.events.subscribe(EVENTSLUG_STAMP_UPDATE, () => {
  console.log("Event gets gets handled!");
  // Do some code here. This code gets done to many times.
});
```

So first time real time data comes in I see:

```
Event publish got fired!
Event gets gets handled!
```

in the console. Second time, I see

```
Event publish got fired!
Event gets gets handled!
Event gets gets handled!
```

Third time I see:

```
Event publish got fired!
Event gets gets handled!
Event gets gets handled!
Event gets gets handled!
```

And so on. I’m using socket.io for the real time data. But as I said, filling my code with console logs I came to the conclusion, that only the subscribe event triggers multiple times. Incremented by one each time the event gets published again.

### Edit

I have found a workaround that works:

```
this.events.subscribe(EVENTSLUG_STAMP_UPDATE, () => {
  this.navCtrl.setRoot('ScanSuccessPage').then(() => {
    this.events.unsubscribe(EVENTSLUG_STAMP_UPDATE);
  });
});
```

Comment: Where is this.events.subscribe... ?

Comment: Inside of a constructor of a page that gets set as root like this `navCtrl.setRoot('PageWIthSubscription')`. I have found a workaround, see edit :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I just spent a little while struggling with this as well. The end result for me was that I had the `subscribe()` on a component which was getting destroyed and recreated as I navigated around the application, but I did not have an `OnDestroy` event handler on the component with `unsubscribe()` so every time it got instantiated it added another subscription handler.

NOTE: you must also pass the **same** event handler to `unsubscribe()`, see [Ionic2: Unsubscribe Event to Avoid Duplicate Entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860110/ionic2-unsubscribe-event-to-avoid-duplicate-entries)

Answer (score 1):

Remove it when not more used (sadly it does not use "once")

```
//handler as property
private handler=(args)=>{...};


...    

events.subscribe(handler); 

...

notMoreNeeded(){//call this when you don't want event is shooted more
    this.events.unsubscribe(handler)
}
```

Comment: If you intent to use that subscription when popping back from another page you should probably not place here. ionViewWillUnload might be a better place